# Self sizing Cells,. Autolayout and hidden UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

i am using Autolayout to set automatically the height of a cell. But i want to use some hidden UIViews in my Cells. So in some rows they should be hidden. The problem here is, if the label is still hidden it gets recognized by autolayout and it uses the space.

So i guess i need to update the height of my label, or the height of my Constraints.

What is the correct way if i am using Autolayout to hide UIElements in a Cell?

How can i update an existing (from Storyboard) Constraint?

Edit: Found out that i am able to update Constraints with Storyboard, is that the correct way to handle that? - but which is the correct one to setup the height? (This is just a Demo Project)

[image]

Comment: It might be better to make two different cells (or more if you need them) in IB, and return the one you need depending on the data for that indexPath instead of trying to hide views. That way, each cell can have the correct constraints and size itself appropriately.

Comment: This is the solutution i am now working on it. These would result in about 12 different Prototype Cells, but i guess the performance would still be better. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard task with autolayout. Currently, there are two ways of solving this task:

1. Removing hidden views
2. Changing constraints priority

**Removing of hidden views**

Looks pretty easy and you won't have any problems if you don't use UITableView (you have to put it back in `prepareForReuse`), UICollectionView or your data can appear while you're on screen, where you've just removed views.

Removing of views is "heavy" operation, so you need to think twice, if you pick this way.

In **CustomCell.m**:

```
- (void) prepareForReuse {
 [super prepareForReuse];
 // add removed views again
 // establish constraints
}

- (void) configureCell {
 // check if you need to hide a view
 [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Changing constraints priority**

Assume, you have following cell:

> ---
>
> View A
>
> View B
>
> ---

If B sometimes can be hidden, then specify for View A following constraints:
Space to B with 750
Bottom Space to superview with 500

If you set B as hidden, change space to B = 500, bottom space to superview = 750.

Undo that change in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My Problem here is: I have about 100 rows with multiple optional Labels. For Example for a Notice, or for a Suggestion from my Validator. These Labels are only shown when there is a user interaction (added a notice, input validation) - so i dont know if its better to add this Labels to my Prototype Cells, and remove the before reuse, or add them in my cell (but therefore i still need to remove it before reuse) - So in this case i think the easiest (and best way) would be to add everything that could be visible into my prototype cells and remove them before reuse?

Comment: Ill found out that if i hide the Elements (before reuse) should be bringing a better performance instead of create a new instance if needed. So i this case your Version with prority should be better.