# Unable to simultaneously satisfy height constraints for dynamic cells

Tags: ios, swift

I have table cells which dynamically resizing their height depending on label text size. I also make some of the cells invisible by making their height 0.

In viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
```

And then:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       let item = datasource[indexPath.row]
       if item.isVisible == true {
          return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
       }
       else{
          return 0
       }
   }
```

In the Content View of the uitableviewcell I have label and textfield below it. Like this:

=====================

TopHeightToSuperview

UILabel

BottomSpaceToTextField

UITextField

BottomSpaceToSuperview

=====================

Cells are resizing properly. But I receive this error:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd05ded2150 V:[TitleLabel(17)]   (Names: TitleLabel:0x7fd05ded0760 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-06-29 17:24:03.391 invest.comQA[98164:6141441] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd05deed120 V:|-(15)-[TitleLabel]   (Names: TitleLabel:0x7fd05ded0760, '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd05dee8000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd05deed260 V:[Text Field]-(14)-|   (Names: Text Field:0x7fd05deea9a0, '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd05dee8000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd05deed420 V:[TitleLabel]-(15)-[Text Field]   (Names: Text Field:0x7fd05deea9a0, TitleLabel:0x7fd05ded0760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd05def1f00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd05dee8000(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd05deed420 V:[TitleLabel]-(15)-[Text Field]   (Names: Text Field:0x7fd05deea9a0, TitleLabel:0x7fd05ded0760 )>
```

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26178454/1228534

Comment: try clearing constraints and then adding missing constraints. that seems to magically fix my issues